# Basis for not doing a full sof-aliya trop on Hashem's name

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, shemos-sacred-names, ashkenazi, music

The Ashkenazi leining for the end of an aliya generally has a drop of 4 tones. In my preferred key, that's from D to A (hit `y` then `e` on [this virtual piano](http://virtualpiano.net/)). However, some *baalei kriah* in my shul do not do this when the last word of the aliya is Hashem's name, and instead drop only a single tone (D to C, hit `y` then `t` on that piano).

I would guess that the reason for this is some notion of respect, where they don't want to make such a drop on His name.

Is there any basis in halacha or firmly established minhag for this, or is it merely a personal quirk of a few people?

Comment: I believe I have heard this more prevalently among Jews of German extraction than among other Ashkenazim.

Comment: The notes 'y' and 'e' did not in the virtual piano didn't sound like the 'sof aliyah' trop that I almost universally here.

Comment: I've never heard this (or perhaps not known to listen for it), but I've heard jumping a fifth instead of dropping a fourth (yp instead of ye on that keyboard).

Comment: The Yekkes I've heard have gone up the octave on divine names.

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot If you want to hear it with a lead-in, play `you (tipcha) tyu (mercha) ye (sof-pasuk)`.

Comment: The shamash in the shul I attended mostly in Washngtn Heights didn't do the regualr sof pasuk when the aliyah ended in G-d's name. (For clarity, Noach, my shul was not yekke and the BK was not, either. His trope was "Hungarian" / "chabad" style in minor, FWIW. However, I did frequently attend one of two Yekke shuls in my neighborhood, so I am fairly familiar with their trope.) Shamash explained to me that the "up note" is a sign of respect for Hashem's name. I still practice this minhag. Offhand, I can't really say how common this minhag is now, as I don't have much chance to hear others lain.

Comment: Can't find a source, but I was taught it was to prevent the congregation humming along - and saying The Name in vain -  as some (annoyingly) tend to do as the Aliya ends.

Comment: @DanF - same here, essentially. http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=21547 - המנהג אכן היה קיים באשכנז, ועד היום יוצאי אשכנז נוהגים לפיו. 
הטעם הוא, כאשר מסיימים את הפרשה או חלקה בשם ה', אין לרדת בקול, אלא להיפך, בבחינת "תנו עוז לאלקים" -תהלים סח, לה.  But not an answer as it is not a  credible and/or official source.

Comment: @DannySchoemann "not a credible and/or official source" - I'm inclined to disagree. I have heard of Moreshet and they seem reliable enough, and I would venture that the Rav who responded is reliable as well. You know the rule - אשר יהיה בימים ההם . Unless you have specific reason **not** to trust the rav or Moreshet, I think it's a good answer. We've had a number of answers on this site - some from me - that came from a local rav. You don't personally know my local rav, but, if I claim he's reliable, many here trust my and my rav's opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You asked:

> Is there any basis in halacha or firmly established minhag for this, or is it merely a personal quirk of a few people?

According to Rav [שמואל פנחס גלברד](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/advancedSearchResult.asp?i=0&nop=20&WholeWord=0&rabonim=10115&x=7&y=6) it's a **Minhag** originating in Ashkenaz (Germany, I assume), and to this day Yekkes  lein this way.

He gives a reason that it's more correct (as in honorable) to raise one's tone when saying Hashem's name than to go lower - along the lines
 of (תְּנוּ עֹז לֵא-לֹקִים ([תהלים סח, לה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01451.html#HtmpReportNum0068_L2)  - *attribute Strength to Hashem*.‏

> המנהג אכן היה קיים באשכנז, ועד היום יוצאי אשכנז נוהגים לפיו. הטעם הוא, כאשר מסיימים את הפרשה או חלקה בשם ה', אין לרדת בקול, אלא להיפך, בבחינת "תנו עוז לאלקים" - (תהלים סח, לה).‏

Source: [Shut Moreshet](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=21547)

I grew up in a Yekkish shul and everybody leined like that. I was taught it was to prevent the congregation humming along - and saying The Name of Hashem in vain - as some (annoyingly) tend to do as the Aliya ends.

Source: My grandfathers ז"ל

Comment: Excellent answer!  (If nothing else absolutely fantastic comes along, the bounty is yours.)

Comment: Mind telling me which Yekke shul and where?

Comment: @DanF - Sure! As I've mentioned previously here, the Adas Yeshurun of Johannesburg and the Etz Chaim of Strasbourg.